# Can't publish Laravel app because of ini_set()

Tags: php, laravel, ini-set

I can't seem to get my Laravel application working because my shared hosting has ini_set() disabled. I have found some workarounds which rely on enabling ini_set().

Neither could I do that (I have tried) because my hosting provider doesn't allow it, nor do I want to as it isn't safe. I'm looking for a way to stop Laravel from using the function.

I've found that Laravel is trying to call ini_set('display_errors', Off). I tried removing the debug value from config, cached config and .env and Laravel is still calling the function. I don't need it to do that as my server's settings already have the display_errors as I want it (disabled).

To sum up, I'm looking for a way to stop Laravel from trying to use ini_set. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you checked if laravel is not in debug mode ?

Comment: Contact your hosting sys. admin or modify (if you have access) the php.ini file. Better place for laravel application is VPS not shared hosting.

Comment: @MTroy It's not in debug mode. The problem js that on bootup it's using ini_set to disable displaying errors to the user. I have contacted the IT support, they're a bit reluctant about turning it on, but it seems I might have to insist